# Beta Firebase Firestore won't work with projects using app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

When I try to add the beta firestore to my Google cloud platform project I get the following message.

***Cannot enable Firestore for this project***
Currently Firestore cannot be enabled in projects already using Cloud Datastore or App Engine

Is this going to last forever?
I think I would like to replace some but not all of my datastore stuff with firestore to get realtime updates.

Perhaps firestore uses datastore and appengine in its backend?

Should I use two GCP projects to get around this problem?

Thanks,
Nathan

Comment: Datastore sound kinda similar to Firestore and at the moment Firestore looks like it is straight from GCP into Firebase, like the quotas, rules & similar, so I guess that's the reason.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is currently a technical restriction we hope to remove in the future.

Yes, currently you will need to use 2 separate GCP projects to use both Cloud Datastore and Cloud Firestore simultaneously.

Comment: Any idea if this restriction is going away soon?

Comment: I would *not* be expecting it to go away next year.

Comment: Hey @DanMcGrath I have googling about various sites on three things Firebase Realtime Database, Firestore and also Datastore! Up to now I think Firestore is going to be replacement for both Datastore and RealtimeDatabase because it has features of both. Is this what Google is planning??

Comment: @Xenolion, we generally don't comment on publicly comment on roadmaps.

Comment: Okay.... I will consider that as a YES and implement my next App Engine project with Firestore. Because even the prices of Datastore and Firestore are matching!.

Comment: I guess the Firestore is implemented with Datastore. And that's the reason you can't use both in the same project.

Comment: @Xenolion, I doubt that Datastore or Firebase Realtime Database will be removed in favor of firestore. I think there is still enough people using both and both have things that firestore cannot do.

Comment: I thought about it and realized thats its impossible to  remove datastore when firestore grows I think firestore will just be added as an alternative storage. Because there is also cloud sql databases. Also datastore have memcaches, and other things. Also anyone can make his own firestore! I once has such an idea, because I structure my data in datastore so I only query by keys or ancestor never by `SELECT`  `WHERE`. And firestore is easy to implement. They should just allow us to have datastore and firestore in the same project then! @nburn42

Comment: @DanMcGrath Does that include projects that just use App engine to set up cron jobs? My current firebase rtdb project relies on functions-cron which I set up through App Engine. I want to make sure if I do move over then I can still set up cron jobs through App Engine without setting up two different projects. From your explanation it seems like it's just the Datastore component of App Engine that won't work with a Firestore project.

Comment: @DanMcGrath I used Datastore previously in my production project. Currently I am using Firebase Database with Firebase Authentication with users of my app. I would like to use Firestore for a new feature and use same user base for authorization - I do not care about Datastore at this point anymore. Is there any way I can disconnect/remove whatever is blocking me from using the Firestore if I don't use Datastore directly anymore?

Comment: There are things in datastore that Firestore is not supporting at the moment. Like indeaxable list properties and putting tasks to queues within transaction. Also there are a lot of app already developed for datastore. So I don't see datastore going away anytime soon.